# Should I not use CakePHP or MVC for this app?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, web

I  have been working for a company for the past several months as a kind of general developer/IT guy. I wrote a web app for the company that is hosted locally. I used CakePHP and MySQL (because the application fit the Active Record scheme really well).

The new web app I am working in is going to be used to analyze monthly sales data. Essentially, we get a humongous dump of information every month that I need to analyze...

---

Every month we get a huge table of data that has every one of our clients info (their ID#, how many $$ they processed, how much we made off them, etc.). Call this RESIDUAL

We also get another table that basically has their ID, a "description" (basically the type of expense), and a value. Call this INTERCHANGE

I have a permanent table called REPS that has each Sales Rep ID, their name, etc.

---

In order to get useful information (like the client name), I delete and reupload another table that has info like their Name, State, Status (if they are active or closed), etc... monthly.

I decided to make a residuals table that records the month as a column and I just add to it each month.

---

My problem is that working with CakePHP is getting pretty difficult. Say I want to get a table that has columns for each month and rows for each Sales Rep. It starts to get really complicated because this is NOT an *Active Record* application and I am having to do all sorts of long complicated find statements.

Would you recommend changing to a different framework, language, or database? What changes in Database structure should I make? My Controller is INSANELY long, should I shift more work to the Models?

Any ideas?

---

*Edit*: I need to create a system where my not-as-technical boss can easily run whatever sorts of analyses she wants.

---

*Edit #2*: Thanks for the responses. Yes I know SQL queries pretty well, and I actually started off just doing my own thing, but then I restructured the DB and converted to Cake right after that.

Comment: My advice is to use give your boss a dedicated reporting tool like Crystal Reports and/or learn how to write SQL queries by-hand to extract the data you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an extremely open ended question, as such you won't get a perfect answer. I can only throw in my two cents that Cake is not tuned for a database *heavy* application. By that I mean anything that is not simply CRUD record inserting, retrieving, updating. The Cake DAL does not scale well to accommodate complex queries or mass-data insertion/updating/manipulation.

Having said that, there's still PHP in CakePHP. You can issue "manual" queries using the model's `query` method. You should create methods in a model that does the heavy data lifting; such code is business logic and does not belong in the controller. In the model use regular PHP and SQL code to process data.

If this is pretty much the *only* thing your app does, you may be happier without Cake and just some thin wrapper around your own database connection like PDO. That forgoes Cake's nice routing, forms and views though, so you have to decide what you prefer to spend time on.

Comment: What framework would do a better job for database heavy applications?

Comment: I have no specific recommendation here, but one where the database wrapper is as thin as possible. For complex queries you often really want to write SQL by hand and not have to go through two layers of abstractions. Depending on your app, something like [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) with PDO and a bolted-on templating system can be great, otherwise something like Zend Framework that allows you to choose every part very flexibly.

Answer (score 1):

Examine your options first. Do you know any other frameworks? Do you know how to setup a plane Jane PHP app with your own MVC? A lot of components in frameworks can be found independently and added to your own application (like Active Records, Dependency Injection, Auto Loading etc, etc)

If the framework you are currently using is making it hard for you to get things done, then you should consider getting rid of it. Using a framework should make things easier, not hard. And the thing about CakePHP is that it goes by the mantra 'Convention over Configuration'. While it's great for getting out a certain type of new application off the ground in no time flat, it's not suitable for everything.

Since I don't know much about your project, I can't really help you choose a framework. But from my past experience, Zend Frameowork and CodeIgniter have been the most flexible. ZF also offers a good CLI structure as well, in case you need heavy duty crons running all the time. That being said, use these only if you really need/want a framework.

Having really complex controllers isn't a good thing. This might indicate that your models aren't doing enough work and most of your transformation is happening in your controllers. Your models and your views should be doing the bigger part of the work. I usually aim for thin controllers and fat models.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered other frameworks?

[Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) (I use 1.4.*), for example, can use Propel as its [ORM](http://www.propelorm.org/). Propel is really well designed and it makes use of a Query object that makes getting data from the database really easy. It also allows for custom SQL queries to be written should you need to resort to that.

To answer your question, even though you're asking specifically about Cake PHP it sounds like the "This is too much" argument; as in "Using such and such framework is too much for this project". In my case, I prefer to deploy every project using a framework an [plugins](https://github.com/homer6/sfAltumoPlugin) that I carry with me and invest time in knowing really well. They save me time and I don't have to think about basic plumbing code in every project I start.

A framework provides a lot of tools (besides the ORM), like routing, validation, etc that come very handy in almost any project and not having them really can slow you down a lot.

I would recommend you have a look at other options if you feel CakePHP has become cumbersome as I am very certain using a framework is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good and a bad news for you. The good news is that you started very well with Active Record, and CakePHP. The bad news is that your DB structure is not quite OK.

Read a little about [Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and learn how to normalize your DB and data.

The first problem I see is that you add a column for each month. You should really have 2 more different tables:

- 1 for months - this can hold months name, and some super aggregated data like the total amount of sales for that month for the whole company
- 1 that will be the pivot table between REPS and months - in this you'll hold rep's id, month_id and possibly some information related to the sales of that rep for that month.

In the end you will have a [many-to-many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relation between reps and months. ActiveRecord will be more than happy, the MVC also, and also the developers that will work with or after you because this is how it should be done :)